# opening a reverse tunnel for public

Tags: ubuntu, port, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

Hello on Machine A I have a camera that with a webserver on port 60000 behind NAT that connects to Machine B using "**autossh -M 0 -R 60000:localhost:60000 -p 5000 user@public_ip**" (port 5000 is my SSH. On Machine B, I can see the server on localhost:60000 . I want to be able to access this from my public_ip:60000 from Machine C, Machine B has a public ip, that I already can access. How is this possible, Im using Ubuntu 14.04 for both machines, also is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** uncomment **GatewayPorts Yes**, restart, and it'll work perfectly.